# Special characters in EBS Search Strings?

Tags: regex, string, sap-erp

I am working on the EBS configuration side of the SAP ERP system where I am trying to define Search Strings for the MT940 format (as per SAP `SPRO` activity "Define Search String for Electronic Bank Statement", for instance see this [blog post](https://blogs.sap.com/2020/08/05/search-string-in-electronic-bank-reconciliation-mt940-format-part-ii/)).

I am trying to create a search pattern that is able to identify special characters in the MT940 format, for example `?/!/>`, etc.

My search pattern: `\C*######\C*`

The text that I use to identify the mapping:

```
:86:306?00CCY RECD?20/BI/**?651234?**/BO/DE652004ED
```

In this case, I defined:

- `\C*` as to look for special characters - this will be skipped based on the mapping.
- `#` to look for a sequence of 6 numbers.

My results from the test:

```
1    651234
2    652004
3    651234
4    652004
```

The result I look to achieve based on the search pattern defined: `651234`

I do understand that the reason for having the repetition is because of the `*` symbol. However, if I skip adding that symbol, the search pattern will end up in error.

My problem is that I cannot seem to understand **how can I translate special characters to be identified by the SAP Search Strings**?  Furthermore, **how can I identify if it is a letter**?

Below is the Search String definition from the SAP documentation of `SPRO` activity "Define Search String for Electronic Bank Statement":

```
String for searches in text. A search string consists of normal characters (that is, letters and digits) and other characters:

|   Or

( ) Grouping

+   Repeats the previous character once or several times

*   "Zero" or repeats the previous character several times

?   Any individual character you want

#   Any of the digits 0 to 9

^   Start of a line

$   End of a line

\   Escape symbol

Examples:

The search string "ab" fits each position in a character string in which the letter "b" follows the letter "a".

The search string "(A+|B)+C" "AC", "BC", "AAAAAC" or "ABAAC".

"(A+|B+)C fits "AC", "BC" and "AAAAAC", but not "ABAAC".

"\*C" fits "*C"; the effect of the escape symbol is that "*" is not interpreted as a special character.
```

This is the first time I raise a question, therefore, I want to apologize if the format is not correct or the text was too long.

Many thanks for your time and help!

Comment: Why do you think "\C" looks for 'special characters', that looks for the letter C? I guess you are looking for `\?######\?` ...

Comment: I have just assumed that based on the following sentence: `\*C" fits "*C"; the effect of the escape symbol is that "*" is not interpreted as a special character.`
 
If I do the following change `\?######\?` the string will basically identify only the patterns that have as a symbol in the beginning "?". I re-tested now again the search pattern defined initially and it seems that it works. So with \C, we can take every special character like ! or ?. However, I still do not feel confident with the solution.

Comment: Please make yourself familiar with [escape characters](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character). You completely missread the documentation.

Comment: The C is just a C like the A is an A in the other example.

Comment: This question is not about ABAP programming, it's a question about customizing in SAP ERP (in ABAP Regular Expressions, **#** doesn't mean a digit), but I think this question is valid for Stack Overflow as it seems to be almost like Regular Expressions, so many people can help.

Comment: ``\C*` is completely ignored because it means zero or any number of character `C`, and so any sequence of 6 digits will be found. According to SAP ERP documentation, you can only list explicitly all the special characters that you want to use, for instance `(!|?|%)`.

Comment: @SandraRossi, yes, that I was afraid of. It is clear bright now. Many thanks for your time.